# Excel VBA - how to rename sheets based on missing sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I've just written some code to go through all files within a folder, search the workbooks for sheets of specific names, and then remove all said sheets (see below - I'm sure there are cleaner ways of writing it, but I'm not a dev). What I'm left with are sheets that aren't in order (i.e. sheet1, sheet2, sheet4, sheet5 - missing sheet3). What I want to do is shift the names of all the sheets down based on the sheets missing, so sheet4 in the example above, would become sheet3 etc. But there are also other sheets missing later on in the workbook (i.e sheet40, sheet41, sheet43 - missing sheet 42), which would mean that the later sheets would have to move X number of spaces depending on the number of sheets that are missing.

The only way that I can think of it working, would be to create a list of all the sheets that should be there, i.e. sheet1 through to sheetX, and then reference this list when renaming the existing sheets. Am I even close?

```
Sub AllFiles()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook

folderPath = "C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Desktop\something\macro_test\"

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls")
Do While filename <> ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
     
    'Call a subroutine here to operate on the just-opened workbook
    Call Mymacro
    
    
    filename = Dir
Loop
```

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

```
    Sub Mymacro()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If Sheet.Name = "code_D_1" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_2" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_3" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_4" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_5" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_6" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_7" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_8" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_9" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_10" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_11" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_12" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_13" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_14" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_15" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_16" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_17" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_18" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_19" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_20" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_21" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_22" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_23" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_24" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_25" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_26" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_27" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_28" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_29" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_30" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_31" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_32" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_33" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_34" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_35" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_36" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_37" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_38" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_39" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_40" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_41" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_42" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_43" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_44" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_45" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_46" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_47" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_48" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_49" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_50" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_51" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_52" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_53" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_54" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_55" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_56" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_57" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_58" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_59" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_60" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_61" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_62" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_63" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_64" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_65" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_66" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_67" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_68" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_69" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_70" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     
     End If
Next Sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: After deletion, do you just want to rename the remaning sheets to "sheet1", "sheet2,... in order for as many sheets there are in the book? Or what do you mean by move?

Comment: And irrelevant to the question, but; is the number in `Sheet.Name = "code_D_x"` relevant, or do you just want to delete anything starting with *code_D_*? Because then you could do a bit of a wildcard approach.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. I am deleting all sheets that have 'code_D_(number)' in them. Afterwards, I'm just looking to rename sheets

Comment: You say "sheet1" and so on in the question, but they are supposed to be "code_n_x"? Easy enough to change in the code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code, where I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible:

```
Sub delRename()
Dim i As Long, Sheet As Variant
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
i = 1
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(Sheet.Name, 7) = "code_D_" Then
        Sheet.Delete
    ElseIf Left(Sheet.Name, 7) = "code_n_" then
        Sheet.Name = "code_n_" & i
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next Sheet
End Sub
```

It goes through the sheets in the active book, and deletes all the sheets starting with the name *"code_D_"* by using the Left() function.
For the sheets named *"code_n_"*, it changes the name to be in order.

Note that if the sheets named "code_n_X" are out of order, this might fail, as the name is already taken.
IF that is a concern, you'd have to add a check for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has three significant parts. Each one is a worthy question by itself. All three together are a project and not a question to be answered here. The parts are (1) loop through all files in a folder and open all workbooks. (2) delete specified sheets and (3) rename the remaining sheets.

Part 1 you seem to have good control of. Part 3 isn't specified sufficiently to enable an answer and for part 2 a solution is offered below.

```
Private Sub DeleteSheets(Wb As Workbook)
    ' 270
    
    Const FileName  As String = "Code_D_"
    Const FirstFile As Integer = 2
    Const LastFile  As Integer = 70
    
    Dim Fn          As String               ' loop variable: file name
    Dim i           As Integer              ' loop counter: file names
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = FirstFile To LastFile
        Fn = FileName & i
        Wb.Worksheets(Fn).Delete
        If Wb.Worksheets.Count = 1 Then Exit For
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Your question isn't sufficiently specific but the core of this task is to create the sheet names. Your code specifies the core name to be "Code_D_" with a serial number following. If this number isn't consecutive from lowest to highest you might add  exclusions using IF statements just before the `Delete` instruction. If the pattern I chose isn't the one that's needed than another must be designed once the requirements are known.

You can call the above sub with a procedure like the one below.

```
Private Sub Test_DeleteSheets()
    ' 270
    
    Dim Wb      As Workbook
    
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    DeleteSheets B
End Sub
```

In fact, your procedure that loops through all the workbooks produces a workbook object by the name of `Wb`. So, you would only need to integrate the last line of this procedure into your existing one.

Witness that the scope of the first procedure above is `Private` because it will only be called from another procedure in the same module. I made the calling procedure also `Private` because it isn't intended to be called from any other location but the module it's in. Your looping procedure probably needs to be `Public` (by default) but it must be in the same module as the `Private` procedure it calls.

Comment: Sorry. My description is rather poor. I wasn't really sure how to explain it and was hoping that the above was sufficient. Thank you for you above answer. As for the part that you reference as part 3, hopefully this is a better explanation. I have a bunch of sheets titled 'code_n_1' through to 'code_n_65'(ish). But there are some sheets missing from the naming conventions. For example, in some sheets, 'code_n_10' might be missing, but sheet'code_n_11' exists. How do I write a piece of code that recognises the missing sheets, and moves the rest down an integer.

Comment: The same sheets aren't missing from every file, so the code needs to identify which of the 65 (or thereabouts) existing 'code_n_x' is missing, and then rename the higher sheets so that there are no names missing. By the end of the file, each of the workbooks should contain sheets titled 'code_n_1' through to 'code_n_65' (ish), consecutively, without there being any sheets out of order (i.e. none having 'code_n_3' or 'code_n_52', or 'code_n_16' missing from the sheet list). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If all sheets are named "Code_D_xx" and all 70 of them are deleted none will remain. Therefore I have modified my above code to prevent deletion of the last worksheet. As for part 3 please ask another question where you have room enough to explain all details without resorting to use the discussion section.

Comment: I dont know if this is allowed, but here is a link to the file. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eGkW1_1SRYk3_rwMZt23dxUAR-S-JhLu/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

### Delete and Rename Worksheets

- You only run your modified `AllFiles` procedure. The other two are being called by it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AllFiles()
    
    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Desktop\something\macro_test\"
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
    
    Dim fName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    fName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls")
    Do While fName <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & fName)
        DeleteSheetsStartingWith wb, "code_D_"
        RenameSheetsWithIncrement wb, "code_D_"
        'wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        fName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub

Sub RenameSheetsWithIncrement( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal BaseName As String, _
        Optional ByVal FirstIndex As Long = 1)
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     
    Dim n As Long: n = FirstIndex
    
    Dim sh As Object
    
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        sh.Name = BaseName & n
        n = n + 1
    Next sh
    
End Sub

Sub DeleteSheetsStartingWith( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal BaseString As String)
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim shNames() As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim FoundVisible As Boolean
    
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If InStr(1, sh.Name, BaseString, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            If sh.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
                sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            End If
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve shNames(1 To n)
            shNames(n) = sh.Name
        Else
            If Not FoundVisible Then
                If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                    FoundVisible = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sh
    
    If FoundVisible Then
        If n > 0 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb.Worksheets(shNames).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'Else ' No sheets to delete.
        End If
    'Else ' No visible sheets would be left.
    End If

End Sub
```

### EDIT

- The `RenameSheetsWithIncrement` procedure is not used in the following procedure.

```vb
Sub AllFiles()
    
    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Desktop\something\macro_test\"
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
    
    Dim fName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim n As Long
    
    fName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls")
    Do While fName <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & fName)
        DeleteSheetsStartingWith wb, "code_D_"
        n = 0
        For Each sh In wb.Sheets
            If InStr(1, sh.Name, "code_n_", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                n = n + 1
                sh.Name = "code_n_" & n
            End If
        Next sh
        'wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        fName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks VBasic2008, thanks for the script. It does pretty much what is needed, except after deleting all the sheets that are required ('code_D_x'), it relabels every remaining sheet within the workbook as 'code_D_x' rather than only searching through the sheets for those that now begin with 'code_n_x' and re-ordering these, whilst leaving the rest as they were. By the end, all the sheets should be the same as they were, and all the 'code_n_x' sheets should be in order beginning at 'code_n_1'. Are you able to modify the script to do the above?? it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sure. I didn't notice the difference between `code_D_x` and `code_n_x`. I'll look into it shortly.

Comment: I've added another version.